# Doctrine ORM object type column not being serialized

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a REST api and I have a column of type object as a property of my User class.  In my User entity I have:

```
/**
 * @var stdClass
 * @Serializer\Expose
 * @Serializer\Groups({"list", "details"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="object", name="notifications")
 */
protected $notifications;
```

When a new user is created, I initialize this field using default values for the different notifications like so:

```
$_notifications = new \stdClass();

$_notifications->voucherSold = true;
$_notifications->voucherRedeemed = true;
$_notifications->newConnection = true;

$user->setNotifications($_notifications);
```

I can see this field is being written to the database correctly.  In my db, under the `notifications` column, I get:

```
O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:11:"voucherSold";b:1;s:15:"voucherRedeemed";b:1;s:13:"newConnection";b:1;}
```

But when I load this User via the API, I end up with an empty object in the notifications field:

```
{
  "resource": "vendors/39",
  "id": 39,
  "email": "test@user.com",
  "notifications": {},
  "company": "",
  "address": "",
  "city": "",
  "state": "",
  "zipcode": "",
  "phone": "",
  "website": ""
}
```

I can't figure out why the value isn't coming through.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: My best guess is that the json encoder can't handle objects - only arrays. You may need to cast the notifications object to an array before returning it.

Comment: @samlev that did the trick.  If you submit an answer to this effect, I will gladly accept it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json encoder may only convert arrays to json, and will simply set an object as an object `{}` instead of looking into it for fields, etc.

Try casting the `$_notifications` object to an array before returning it:

```
$user->setNotifications((array) $_notifications);
```